# Gsub function issue in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm attempting to create a function to create prepared statements for Salesforce queries. The requirement is to escape single quotes; other characters are escaped by Salesforce. When I call

`prepared_query('Select Id from Account where Id = :id and Name = :name limit 1', {:id => '00001234', :name => "John 'Smith"}`

the expected output is

`"Select Id from Account where Id = '00001234' and Name = 'John \'Smith' limit 1"`

I'm attempting to use `gsub` for this. My function is

```
def prepared_query(soql, *args)
        if args[0].is_a? Hash
                args[0].each do |key, val|
                        val.gsub!("'", %q(\\\'))
                        soql.gsub! ":#{key}", "'#{val}'"
                end
        end
end
```

The output is

`"Select Id from Account where Id = '00001234' and Name = 'John  limit 1Smith' limit 1"`

What is causing this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use gsub with two arguments, the replacement string is interpreted in a special way. What is relevant to your case is that `\'` is replaced with the affix of your match (the counterpart to `$'` in ordinary replacement). In order to avoid that you have to use a block for gsub.

A fix to your code may be like this:

```
def prepared_query(soql, h = {})
  h.each do |key, val|
    val.gsub!("'", %q(\\\'))
    soql.gsub!(":#{key}"){"'#{val}'"}
  end
  soql
end
```

Comment: This doesn't work as expected and gives the output `"Select Id from Account where Id = '00001234' and Name = 'John \\'Smith' limit 1"`

Comment: Isn't that what you wanted? What did you wanted, then?

Comment: No. There is an extra `\\`.

Comment: Where? Show the string you wanted.

Comment: My expected output is `"Select Id from Account where Id = '00001234' and Name = 'John \'Smith' limit 1"` as it states in the question.

Comment: That means you do not have to replace the single quote at all. The string you gave right above is equivalent to `"Select Id from Account where Id = '00001234' and Name = 'John 'Smith' limit 1"`.

Comment: Sorry, you were right - I was outputting the string with `p` instead of `print`. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Try:**

```
def prepared_query(soql, *args)
    if args[0].is_a? Hash
            args[0].each do |key, val|                        
                    soql.gsub! ":#{key}", "#{val.inspect}"
            end
    end
    soql
end
```